# Is $x^6-x^3+1$ irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

Is $x^6-x^3+1$ irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$?

**Approach**

If $x^6-x^3+1$ is reducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$, then it can be factored out with degree $1,2\;\text{or}\;3$.

So check that $x^6-x^3+1$ has a root over $\mathbb Z_2[x]\;\text{and}\;\mathbb Z_3[x]$

Then it has no roots in $\mathbb Z_2[x]\;\text{and}\;\mathbb Z_3[x]$

For degree $1$, $(x-1)$ and $(x+1)$ are not possible cases.

Hence I conclude that $x^6-x^3+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z[x]$

Thus $x^6-x^3+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$

My Question is that the first assumption, if $x^6-x^3+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$, then it can be factored out with degree $1,2\;\text{or}\;3$, is whether valid or not valid.

**EDIT**

$x^6-x^3+1$ has a root $2$ over $\mathbb Z_3[x]$

So, my attempts was false.

Comment: If $x^6-x^3+1$ is *reducible* then it has a factor of degree $1$, $2$, or $3$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Oh, I've missed.. I'll edit

Comment: There is a quite common mistake here: if a polynomial has no roots it does no mean that it is irreducible. Moreover, you should note that in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ you have $$x^6-x^3+1 = (x^2-x+1)^3$$ which is surely a reducible polynomial!

Comment: @Crostul Yeah, you're right. I've missed that $\;2\;$ is a root of $x^6-x^3+1$ in $\mathbb Z_3[x]$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$It seems proving irreducibility of $x^6 - x^3 + 1$ in $\Z[x]$ can reduced to an application of [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) by the substitution $x = y - 1$.

Comment: OH..., the substituion is valid since $\mathbb Q[y-1]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[x]$? I never understood Eisenstein's criterion in this way..  intuitive

Comment: Yes, exactly, just use the universal property of polynomials ring (can expand in case). A similar substitution is a routinely employed to prove that the $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial $x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + \dots + x + 1$ is irreducible over the integers, for $p$ a prime.

Answer (score 5):

$$x^6-x^3+1 = \frac{x^9+1}{x^3+1} = \frac{(x^{18}-1)(x^3-1)}{(x^9-1)(x^6-1)} = \Phi_9(-x)=\Phi_{18}(x) $$
and every [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$: in this case, as already shown by Andreas Caranti, it is enough to replace $x$ with $y-1$ and apply Eisenstein's criterion. An alternative is given by checking that $x^6-x^3+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{29}$.

Comment: I should have recognized a cyclotomic polynomial - my bad, +1 to you.

Comment: @user26857: well, it is useful, indeed: since $\Phi_9(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, $\Phi_9(-x)$ is irreducible too.