# Irreducibility of $x^3-6x-2$ in $Q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, substitution, discriminant

Please help me to answer the following problem:

> Let $f(x)=x^3-6x-2\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $L$ be a splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Show that $f$ is irreducible  in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and compute the discriminant of $f(x)$.

Thanks

Comment: It has no rational roots. Check $\pm 1,\pm 2$.

Comment: Compare [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2621387/let-px-x3-6x-6) from yesterday; or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578258/is-x6-x31-irreducible-over-mathbb-qx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Eisenstein's criterion for $p=2$.

See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion

Assume that $x_i$ they are roots of $f$, $x_1+x_2+x_3=3u$, $x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=3v^2$ and $x_1x_2x_3=w^3$.

Hence, $u=0$, $v^2=-2$ and $w^3=2$.

Thus, $$\Delta=(x_1-x_2)^2(x_1-x_3)^2(x_2-x_3)^2=27(3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6)=756$$

Comment: with what prime number i use it?

Comment: An intuitive choice is $2$.

Comment: ok and what about the discreminant how to find it?

Comment: I added something. See now.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg, $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are arbitrary in $\mathbb{Q}$? and why you compute $(x_1-x_2)^2(x_1-x_3)^2(x_2-x_3)^2$?

Comment: Because it's the discriminant and $x_i$ there are roots of the polynomial.

Comment: and how you determined the three equations that relate the roots? in the answer of  Mostafa he find -756? where is the problem?

Comment: See please my post. I fixed some typo.

Comment: @Michal Rozenberg, in the answer of Mostafa he find $-756$ is that correct?

Comment: It's depend on the definition of the discriminant. I like the definition $\Delta=(x_1-x_2)^2(x_1-x_2)^2(x_2-x_3)^2$. In the Mustafa's definition $\Delta=-(x_1-x_2)^2(x_1-x_2)^2(x_2-x_3)^2$. The essence is the same.

Comment: ok and how you determined the three equations where we have $u,v$ and $w$? are they general?

Comment: Do you mean for the polynomial of degree $n$?

Comment: i mean those equation: $x_1+x_2+x_3=3u$, $x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=3v^2$ and $x_1x_2x_3=w^3$? from where did they come?

Comment: They are assumptions only. Just I think  it's better to work with these substitutions.

Comment: In general what is the resul of $x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3$ using the coefficien of the polynomial?

Comment: For $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$, where $a\neq0$ we have $x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=\frac{c}{a},$ $x_1+x_2+x_3=-\frac{b}{a}$ and $x_1x_2x_3=-\frac{d}{a}.$

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and observe that $\pm1,\pm2$ are not roots.

Indeed each rational solution x must be in the form $x = \frac{p}{q}$ with

- p integer factor of the constant term $a_0=-2$
- q integer factor of the leading coefficient $a_3=1$.

Answer (score 2):

you can use irreducible mod $p$. If $p=5$, then $x^3-6x-2\equiv x^3+4x+3\pmod 5$ and we note that $x^3+4x+3$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z_5[x]$

Discriminant of $f(x)$ is $-(4(-6)^3+27(-2)^2)=756$.

Comment: how you calculate the discriminant? is it a general rule?

Comment: if $f(x)=x^3+px+q$, then the discriminant is equal $4p^3+27q^2$

Comment: how to prove that general rule?

Comment: yes, I research the book where you can proved it

Comment: the discriminant of $f(x)=x^3+px+q$ is $-(4p^3+27q^2)$

Comment: more generally, the discriminant of $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ is $-4a^3c+a^2b^2+18abc-4b^3-27c^2$. you can see it in the book: '' rational points on Elliptic curves", Silverman and Tate, p45

Comment: thanks Mustafa!

Comment: You know that the discriminant is a symmetric function of p, q. It is homogeneous of degree 6, thus p muat occur with degree 3 and q with degree 2. On balance, disc (f) =Ap^3+Bq^2. To compute the numbers A, B, use your two favourite polynomials! For example f(x) =x(x-1)(x+1)= x^3-x has p=-1 and disc(f) =4,thus A=-4. Furthermore f(x) =(x-1)(x-w)(x-w^2)= x^3-1, where w is a 3-th root of unity has q=-1 and disc(f) =(1-w) ^2(1-w^2)^2(w-w^2)^2 =... =27,thus B=-27 (you can use w^2=-w-1)